# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE In THE SAME ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to create Chart analist, I want to record what was done on that day. I looked everywhere and can not find how to make to work, I find someting but is not good the insert, here I have the code

```
$mysqli->query('
INSERT INTO chart_sales (date, sales_order) VALUES (Now(), sales_order +1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sales_order =VALUES(+1)');
 $rslt = mysql_query($stmt);
```

how to record what was done on that day, and if you put another date to generate another ID ?

Here is my DATABASE TABEL

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `chart_sales`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `chart_sales`;
CREATE TABLE `chart_sales` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `sales_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of chart_sales
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` VALUES ('1', '2015-09-11', '1');
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` VALUES ('2', '2015-09-11', '1');
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` VALUES ('3', '2015-09-11', '1');
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` VALUES ('4', '2015-09-11', '1');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few syntax errors. Here is what you are shooting for:

```
INSERT INTO chart_sales (date, sales_order) VALUES (Now(), someValue) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sales_order =sales_order +1
```

You need a **UNIQUE KEY** on `date`.

The key for it to work is that the schema must have existing unique key, be it `Primary Key` (PK) or `unique key` that is a clash candidate. In your case all you have is the PK. You need a **UNIQUE KEY** on `date`

You can have many unique key candidates for the `clash`, all it takes is one.

So, if you are not presenting a duplicate id, it will be an `INSERT`. If there would be a `clash`, then the `UPDATE` happens.

Note: `clash` means an attempt that would otherwise violate uniqueness, which is a good thing here, because of the statement, the UPDATE happens.

### Putting it all together then

```
CREATE TABLE `chart_sales` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `sales_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  unique key(`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `chart_sales` (date,sales_order) VALUES ('2015-09-11',1) on duplicate key update sales_order=sales_order+1;
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` (date,sales_order) VALUES ('2015-09-22',1) on duplicate key update sales_order=sales_order+1;
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` (date,sales_order) VALUES ('2015-09-22',1) on duplicate key update sales_order=sales_order+1;
INSERT INTO `chart_sales` (date,sales_order) VALUES ('2015-09-22',1) on duplicate key update sales_order=sales_order+1;
```

...

```
select * from chart_sales;
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | date       | sales_order |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | 2015-09-11 |           1 |
|  2 | 2015-09-22 |           3 |
+----+------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: works fine, whit unique key. When put in on that day exp:                   VALUES ('1', '2015-09-11', '5'); and I change the date to VALUES ('1', '2015-09-12', '1'); remains 1 count but generates ID 3 on hiden value, and again i change data back to ('1', '2015-09-11', '5') but generate other ID like ('8', '2015-09-11', '5') depends on how many times I counted

Comment: ok see bottom section of Answer now. You don't specify the `id`, let the db engine auto_inc for you. Works fine with `now()` btw

Comment: It seems to be a problem, when put two times to count works fine, but the the third generate other ID on the same date why ?

Comment: stick the **whole** thing in a pastie.org if you want me to look at it. I showed you my new table create and inserts, works. **Gotta see it**. Note my comment 2 up. You need to create a test table like I did, you need to do the inserts like I did

Comment: and when I was count three times is not working. And if you put another date generate another ID, Every time I try to count

Comment: right, you did not create the table like I did, or did you? Because you did not show me that you did, and here I am left guessing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89421/discussion-between-razvan-and-drew).